# Valid Username without Regex

Tags: java, string

The Question is to check a valid username:

Conditions are:

1.The username consists of 8 to 30 characters inclusive. If the username consists of less than 8 or greater than 30 characters, then it is an invalid username.

2.The username can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores (_). Alphanumeric characters describe the character set consisting of lowercase characters [a-z], uppercase characters [A-Z], and digits [0-9].

3.The first character of the username must be an alphabetic character, i.e., either lowercase character [a-z] or uppercase character [A-Z].

Sample Input:

8

Julia

Samantha

Samantha_21

1Samantha

Samantha?10_2A

JuliaZ007

Julia@007

_Julia007

Sample Output:

Invalid

Valid

Valid

Invalid

Invalid

Valid

Invalid

Invalid

I am getting wrong output to some cases.

For Input: JuliaZ007 , I should get Valid but getting Invalid. Remaining are correct.

Can I know what's wrong in the code.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/valid-username-checker/problem?isFullScreen=false

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int flag=1;
    int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    while (n-- != 0) {
        String userName = scan.nextLine();
        char a[] = userName.toCharArray();
        String specialCharactersString = "!@#$%&*()'+,-./:;<=>?[]^`{|}";
        for (int i=0;i<userName.length();i++)
        {
        char ch = userName.charAt(i);
        if(specialCharactersString.contains(Character.toString(ch)) && Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)==false) 
        {
            flag=0;
        }
        }
        if (userName.length()>=8 && userName.length()<=30 && Character.isLetter(a[0])==true && flag==1)                   {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("InValid");
        }           
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "*I am getting wrong output to some cases*" - Which ones? What is the expected and what the observed output? Please [edit] the post and add those information.

Comment: @Turing85 For Input: JuliaZ007 , I should get Valid but getting Invalid.

Comment: The Hackerrank question expects a solution WITH regular expression.

Comment: @hfontanez yeah, but i want to try without it . Can you help.

Comment: It would be easier to think about if there was a function whose sole purpose was to validate a username amd that was the only code shown.

Comment: @Suhas The regex I came up with for HackerRank is the same that JavaMan used in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

### With Regex

In your case regular expression is most appropriate:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Solution {
    private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "^[a-zA-Z][\\w_]{7,29}$";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);

        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        while (n-- != 0) {
            String userName = scan.nextLine();
            if (pattern.matcher(userName).matches())
                System.out.println("Valid");
            else
                System.out.println("InValid");
        }
    }

}
```

---

### Without Regex

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        while (n-- != 0) {
            String userName = scan.nextLine();
            if (isValid(userName))
                System.out.println("Valid");
            else
                System.out.println("InValid");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String userName) {
        if (!Character.isAlphabetic(userName.charAt(0))
                || userName.length() < 8
                || userName.length() > 30)
            return false;
        for (char c : userName.toCharArray()) {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) && c != '_')
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

### Explain what causes the problem in the program

Your problem is caused by the `flag`.

Before `JuliaZ007`, you have the name `Samantha?10_2A`, but this name sets the `flag` to `0`.
And when you are in the `JuliaZ007`, the `flag` is always `0` and you get a `InValid`.

To correct this problem, you can reset `flag` to `1` on each new name.
For this, you can simply move the `int flag = 1` in the while.

##### Example :

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        while (n-- != 0) {
            int flag = 1;
            String userName = scan.nextLine();
            char a[] = userName.toCharArray();
            String specialCharactersString = "!@#$%&*()'+,-./:;<=>?[]^`{|}";
            for (int i = 0; i < userName.length(); i++) {
                char ch = userName.charAt(i);
                if (specialCharactersString.contains(Character.toString(ch))
                        && Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) == false) {
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
            if (userName.length() >= 8 && userName.length() <= 30 && Character.isLetter(a[0]) == true && flag == 1) {
                System.out.println("Valid");
            } else {
                System.out.println("InValid");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The OP already knows this and wants an answer WITHOUT regex. Read the comments, and when in doubt ask the OP. You may be right and this may be the best answer, but it is not helpful to the OP because it is not what it was asked.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. We should rather explain what causes the problem and how our solution fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you @ hfontanez @Turing85 for your recommendations, I improved my answer.

Comment: Thank you @JavaMan I got the correct output.

Comment: You're welcome @Suhas, don't hesitate to validate the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> The username consists of 8 to 30 characters inclusive. ***If the username consists of less than 8 or greater than 30 characters, then it is an invalid username***.

```
boolean valid = true;
if (userName.length() < 8 || userName.length() > 30) { 
    valid = false;
}
```

> The username can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores

```
if (valid) {
    for (int  i = 0; i < userName.length(); i++) {
        boolean temp = c
        Character c = userName.charAt(i);
        valid = Character.isLetterOrDigit(c);
        // before invalidating, check to see if it is an underscore
        if (!valid) {
            valid = c == '_';
            if (!valid)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> The first character of the username must be an alphabetic character

```
if (valid) {
    valid = Character.isLetter(userName.charAt(0));
}
```

Once you execute all validation steps, simply `return valid;`. On a side note, you can check the rule of the first character while looping to check the validity of the remaining character. I just did separate checks for clarity and for separating all three requirements for validation.

LASTLY, I want to point out this is most likely NOT the most optimal solution for non-regex. However, I broke it down in these steps because I feel strongly that as a beginner developer, you should attack problems in this manner: first break down the problem into individual, smaller problems. Then, come up to the solution of each independently, and lastly, integrate the smaller solutions into the final product.

Comment: "*2.The username can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores (_)*" - You missed that part of the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Note that methods in class `java.lang.Character`, such as `isLetterOrDigit`, will check for characters (or digits) in **any** language.

Since your question stipulates that the digits must be those commonly referred to as [arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) and the letters must be those in the [English alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet), the below code uses the [unicode code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Architecture_and_terminology) of each character in the user-entered `userName`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result;
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        while (n-- != 0) {
            result = "invalid";
            String userName = scan.nextLine();
            int len = userName.length();
            if (len >= 8  &&  len <= 30) {
                char[] letters = userName.toCharArray();
                if ((letters[0] >= 65  &&  letters[0] <= 90)  ||  (letters[0] >= 97  &&  letters[0] <= 122)) {
                    int i = 1;
                    for (; i < len; i++) {
                        if ((letters[i] >= 48  &&  letters[i] <= 57)  ||
                            (letters[i] >= 65  &&  letters[i] <= 90)  ||
                            (letters[i] >= 97  &&  letters[0] <= 122) ||
                            (letters[i] == 95)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    if (i == len) {
                        result = "valid";
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

Just for the sake of it, here is a solution that uses the [stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result;
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        while (n-- != 0) {
            result = "invalid";
            String userName = scan.nextLine();
            int len = userName.length();
            if (len >= 8  &&  len <= 30) {
                char letter = userName.charAt(0);
                if ((letter >= 65 && letter <= 90) || (letter >= 97 && letter <= 122)) {
                    if (userName.chars()
                                .skip(1L)
                                .allMatch(c -> (c >= 48  &&  c <= 57)  || // c is a digit
                                               (c >= 65  &&  c <= 90)  || // c is uppercase letter
                                               (c >= 97  &&  c <= 122) || // c is lowercase letter
                                               (c == 95))) { // c is underscore
                        result = "valid";
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but you can simply update the range of number of characters. Here's an example of regex.

```
/^(?=.{6,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/
```